# Change default OS loading

Tags: ubuntu, root, grub, mbr, defaults

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 Feb 2014 - upgraded to 14.04LTS. 
I believe there is still remnants of older OS's still there somewhere, (they appear on the Grub multi-boot menu at start up).

An earlier version is now the default OS, however, I found by scrolling down the Grub multi-boot screen to the 5th option, I can access to the current working edition of 14.04LTS.

Naturally, I wish to make this the default.

I have edited `/etc/default/grub` to “`default="4"`”, saved & “`update-grub`” to boot in to the option on the 5th line down automatically. 
 The `/etc/default/grub` now shows:-

- `GRUB_DEFAULT="4"`
- GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
- GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
- GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
- GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Unfortunately this has made no difference to the boot up sequence, I still have to select the 5th line to access a working OS.

I now suspect that editing `/etc/default/grub` is not reaching deep enough into `Root` or `MBR` which might explain why my changes have been unsuccessful.

Is there a way of ensuring the `Grub` file is the right one in `Root` or `MBR`?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please could you change backslashes with common slashes?

Comment: After running update-grub, check if grub.cfg is modified.

Comment: I believe that this extract from /boot/grub/ grub.cfg shows that it has accepted the change to default=4  
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###  
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then set have_grubenv=true
  load_env fi  
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then  
   set default="${next_entry}"  
   set next_entry=  
   save_env next_entry  
   set boot_once=true  
else
   set default="4"  
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then  
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_opt

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then

Comment: I have changed the direction of the slashes - sorry.

Comment: Modified with new thoughts. Is the version of Grub which I edited deep enough to effect changes?

Comment: Did you run `update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Yes I did run `update-grub`. Having rebooted I checked `/etc/default/grub` and it was changed to show `GRUB_DEFAULT="4"` as shown in the listing above.  Did not have the desired affect though.

Comment: Todays update has changed everything! Ironically in a cleaner  Grub multi-boot screen it selected the 5th option on reboot, which is no longer appropriate! So now I have to change the default back to "0" to engage the 1st option on the menu, then hopefully problem solved!!